# Records in DB that should trigger timed Events = How to implement efficiently?

Tags: java, database, performance, events

**Problem:**

This is a very interesting Problem: I hava a large number of Records in a database that itself have associated with them a "trigger-time" (=a date in the future). If  this time is right/reached, the record should do/fire a specific action. Multiple threads will update this time for a records. So this time is not fixed, it can be changed by the different threads...

**Solutions: 

Polling:**
I can of course over and over query for Records, that have "timedout". In the End I would have to write a loop that only does querying (via SQL), if the event/record has timedout. But this is no good having such a polling loop for a DB!? 

**Threads**: Another approach ist to keep all of them in memory for example with the "Executor Framework" or be using Quartz as Threads. This would be logical from a JAva perspective an most likely very good timed. But then I would have thousands of threads...

**Question:**

What better approaches are there to solve this problem? Any suggestions/ideas are welcome, so I can do a further research on them.

Thank very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the database, some have 'notifications' (I am thinking of Postgres here). It allows you to start up a process and let other things in PG notify you when they happen.

I.e. in this scenario, when a record is changed with a time-out you could have a trigger notifying your timing process (that sits on a totally different DB connection) and it could then insert @at records, or cron entries, or whatever it is you need to do on your side to manage and execute the actions.

In the newest releases of PG, you can send data along with the notify , i.e. you can send the PK value of the record that changed.

```
Clients --> [Postgres]  -----------<> Record Monitor client ---- > process records()
            |                       |
         records_table              |
            |                       |
             \_ timing_Trigger()  --/
                      on_update/insert/delete notify RecordMonitorClientOfChange.
```

A super crappy diagram of what I would do.